# How to monitor password protected web page

Tags: authentication, websites

I want to use a website monitor to check that a web page is working but the web page requires that the user is authenticated.

Is there a crafty way of achieving this that doesn't require storing an authentication ticket with the website monitoring service, where it could be stolen and used to make malicious requests?

Comment: Why not create a page where no authentication is needed just for status checking?

Comment: Or, alternatively, create a minimal access account that can only call HEAD on the top page inside the password-protected tree, and just use that account for monitoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like Pingdoms Transaction Monitor (https://www.pingdom.com/product/transaction-monitoring/), but be aware that you are giving credentials to a public service.

You could also use powershell script or similar to do the same.
See this question on stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282842/how-to-login-to-website-with-basic-authentication-using-powershell

Answer (score -1):

I think you'll have to either make your own website-checking service or set up an intermediary server. If you provide more information about either or both of the services and an alternative exists, I or someone else might be able to get suggest alternatives.